# JPA 2 -- Using @ElementCollection in CriteriaQuery

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

```
    @Entity
    public class Person {

        @ElementCollection
        private List<Location> locations;

        [...]

    }

    @Embeddable
    public class Location {

        private Integer dummy;

        private Date creationDate;

        [...]

    }
```

Given the following structure, I'd like to perform the HQL or CriteriaQuery equivalent of the following SQL:

```
SELECT
    l.*
FROM
    Location l
INNER JOIN
    Person p ON (p.id = l.person_id)
WHERE
    p.id = ? AND l.creationDate > ?
```

I want to get back a list of Locations that are associated with the given person and whose creationDate is after the given one.

Thanks in advance!

Mark

Edit***: I have edited the SQL, as it was kinda misleading. I don't want to query for the locations independently.

Comment: The FROM clause is still querying Location.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is not possible, you cannot query an `Embeddable`. From the JPA Wikibook:

> ### [Embedded Collections](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection#Embedded_Collections)
>
> An `ElementCollection` mapping can be
>   used to define a collection of
>   `Embeddable` objects. This is not a
>   typical usage of `Embeddable` objects
>   as the objects are not embedded in the
>   source object's table, but stored in a
>   separate collection table. This is
>   similar to a `OneToMany`, except the
>   target object is an `Embeddable`
>   instead of an `Entity`. This allows
>   collections of simple objects to be
>   easily defined, without requiring the
>   simple objects to define an `Id` or
>   `ManyToOne` inverse mapping.
>   `ElementCollection` can also override
>   the mappings, or table for their
>   collection, so you can have multiple
>   entities reference the same Embeddable
>   class, but have each store their
>   dependent objects in a separate table.
>
> The limitations of using an
>   `ElementCollection` instead of a
>   `OneToMany` is that **the target
>   objects cannot be queried**,
>   persisted, merged independently of
>   their parent object. They are strictly
>   privately-owned (dependent) objects,
>   the same as an `Embedded` mapping.
>   There is no cascade option on an
>   `ElementCollection`, the target
>   objects are always persisted, merged,
>   removed with their parent.
>   `ElementCollection` still can use a
>   fetch type and defaults to LAZY the
>   same as other collection mappings.

To achieve what you want, use a `OneToMany` and an `Entity` instead of an `ElementCollection` and an `Embeddable`. Or change your approach and query the `Person`.

Comment: Thank for your quick reply. I have edited my first post as it was a bit misleading.

Comment: Though clearly some implementations DO allow querying of embeddable element classes (in embedded collections).

Answer (score 2):

The key phrase in Pascal's reply is

> the target objects cannot be queried, persisted, merged **independently of their parent object**

As you are dependent on the parent object, you should be able to do this using something like ...

`SELECT p FROM PERSON, IN (p.locations) WHERE p.id = ?1 AND locations = ?2`

(Based on the reply at [Execute "MEMBER OF" query against 'ElementCollection' Map fields in JP-QL (JPA 2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548124/execute-member-of-query-against-elementcollection-map-fields-in-jp-ql-jpa-2) - which is actually a Map @ElementCollection which was what I was looking for an answer to!)