# Selecting native collections defined with @ElementCollection from Entities in JPA

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Let's suppose we have an Entity of this type:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User {
  @Id
  long id;

  @ElementCollection
  List<String> phones;
}
```

My goal is to have the complete list of phones, for all users, something like: "SELECT x.phones FROM User x"

I tried to build a Spring Data JPA query of this kind:

```
@Query("SELECT x.phones FROM User x")
List<String> findAllPhones();
```

But I get this exception:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: not an entity
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.renderIdentifierSelect(FromElementType.java:188)
```

I had to resort to a native sql query to solve the problem.
Otherwise I have to wrap the phone number inside a new Entity, but I exactly want to avoid that.

Is there any way to solve this kind of problem using plain JPA or (even better) only Spring Data JPA methods?

Comment: I think what you are trying is not  possible from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708914/jpa-2-using-elementcollection-in-criteriaquery

Comment: I tried to use projections but they show the same error along the expected lines

Comment: this is my exception not an entity [select generatedAlias0.groups from org.User as generatedAlias0]

Comment: Did you solve you problem in the end?

Comment: No, I didn't. I resorted using a native query.