# Spring boot JPA: search entities by field that represent list of embedded objects

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have an entity `Order` with List of options inside, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class OrderEntity extends AuditableEntity {
    private Long passengerId;
    private OrderType type;
    private OrderStatus status;
    @ElementCollection()
    @CollectionTable(name = "options", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id"))
    private List<OrderOptionEntity> options = new ArrayList<>(0);
...
```

And I want to find all orders, matches specified list of options.  I'm using `JpaRepository<OrderEntity, Long>` for CRUD operations. Unfortunately, when I add method `findByOptions`, like this:

```
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderEntity, Long> {
    List<OrderEntity> findAllByOptions(List<OrderOptionEntity> options);
}
```

In tests it throws

> SqlNode's text did not reference expected number of columns;

So now I just do `findAll()` and filter all orders manually. Is there any more elegant way for obtain entities, matching by all elements of list inside it?

**UPDATE**: 
When I run

```
@Query("SELECT ord FROM OrderEntity ord WHERE :options MEMBER OF ord.options")
    List<OrderEntity> findAllByOptions(@Param(value = "options") List<OrderOptionEntity> options);
```

It works fine, but only if  ord.options and options in query has size 1, if more - it throws

> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Invalid argument in JDBC
>   call: parameter index out of range: 3

Generated SQL is

```
 /* SELECT
        ord 
    FROM
        OrderEntity ord 
    WHERE
        :options MEMBER OF ord.options */ select
            orderentit0_.id as id1_3_,
            orderentit0_.version as version2_3_,
            orderentit0_.create_time as create_t3_3_,
            orderentit0_.update_time as update_t4_3_,
            orderentit0_.comment as comment5_3_,
            orderentit0_.distance_to_order as distance6_3_,
            orderentit0_.passenger_id as passenge7_3_,
            orderentit0_.price as price8_3_,
            orderentit0_.route_distance as route_di9_3_,
            orderentit0_.status as status10_3_,
            orderentit0_.type as type11_3_ 
        from
            orders orderentit0_ 
        where
            (
                ? , ?
            ) in (
                select
                    options1_.key,
                    options1_.value 
                from
                    options options1_ 
                where
                    orderentit0_.id=options1_.order_id
            )
```

All what I want - get all Orders, containing some subset of options.

Comment: Yuo can get the OrderEntity form OrderOptionEntity. Will that work?

Answer (score 2):

You probably forgot the `In` keyword in your query method.

Try this

```
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderEntity, Long> {

    List<OrderEntity> findAllByOptionsIn(List<OrderOptionEntity> options);

}
```

Take a look at the [`docs`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation).

Comment: Thanks, I read. But It throws same exception: 
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: SqlNode's text did not reference expected number of columns; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: SqlNode's text did not reference expected number of columns

Comment: Is the column you are joining on is correct `joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")`?

Comment: Can you please debug the code and post the query that runs?!

Comment: Unfortunately no, my skills is not enough, and whith spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true it's not shown.

Comment: Is `OrderOptionEntity` an `@Entity` or an `@Embeddable`? If it is an `@Embeddable` you are probably not able to query for it because of https://stackoverflow.com/a/3709012/923560 .